# Binding to special character in a message - a la Facebook

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

So you know how in Facebook when you type a special character in a post, it brings up (right below your cursor), a list of people's names that start with or feed off of the letters you are typing in at the time?

I would like to achieve a similar functionality, however the source of data won't be peoples names. Actually the source of data really isn't important right now, I'm just trying to figure out the best way to implement that technology.

Is there a plugin for this or is this something I'm going to have to do myself? I was thinking if there wasn't a plugin, to bind (in JQuery), to that specific special character `keypressed` event, and then basically use a tooltip plugin that comes into focus instead of the text field the user was writing in, and fill the tooltip with the things from my Data Source, until they hit 'Esc' to exit, or 'Enter' to select a choice or something.

Any tips/ideas/suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Comment: Well, I don't want the entire text box binded to a list of autocomplete items, just part of the message in the box, a la Facebook, and I want this to be triggered by a special character in the same way they do it.

Comment: The plugin can be adapted to suit that purpose.

Comment: Is there an example how anywhere? I can't find anything that is suited for that purpose on their site at least.

Answer (score 0):

I would indeed go with the keypressed event in JQuery and detect the key. If it's the one you need, show the tooltip.

```
$("#target").keypress(function(e) {
   var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
   if (code == <your_key> {

   }
});
```

Comment: This was more just me throwing out ideas, but are you sure it's the best one?

Comment: There'll be several options. The UI Autocomplete may suffice too. But I'd implement this manually. What's the best one depends on your knowledge and the usage. Up to you to decide!